# Is Ubuntu participating as a mentoring organization in google code in 2018

Tags: google

Last year(2017), Ubuntu participated as a mentoring organization in Google Code-in 2017. Will Ubuntu participate this year too? Asking because I reviewed old stats from archives and saw Ubuntu participated for the first time. CHEERS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Searching https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/ for `Ubuntu` or `Canonical` comes up empty. [GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/Outreach/SummerOfCode) and [KDE](https://community.kde.org/GSoC) are listed.

Searching for `Linux` also doesn't list `Canonical` or `Ubuntu`.

[image: GSOC]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear so. [Google has switched from using Ubuntu to using Debian](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/01/19/googles-linux-workstations-switching-ubuntu-debian/), so that might have something to do with Ubuntu not being part of it this year.

You can still help Ubuntu out by making the things it's built upon better. Here are some projects that Ubuntu is built upon:

- [Debian is the Linux distribution Ubuntu is built upon](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5166394929315840/)
- [GNOME is Ubuntu's standard desktop environment](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5900447454330880/)
- [GNU Compiler Collection is used to compile a lot of Ubuntu's software](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6040623124054016/)
- [GNU Project makes the basic Linux tools used in Ubuntu](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6071880469970944/)
- [KDE Community develops Kubuntu's desktop environment and associated applications](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5582559946211328/)
- [LibreOffice is Ubuntu's standard office suite](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/4535835748204544/)
- [The Linux Foundation supports work on the basics of Linux](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/4687783302529024/)
- [Mozilla makes Ubuntu's default web browser, Firefox](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/4870325653733376/)
- [Python Software Foundation makes the Python programming language used a lot for Ubuntu's tools](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/4812284052897792/)
- [The Qt Project works on a framework used by Kubuntu and a lot of its associated applications](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/5388456415461376/)
- [X.Org Foundation makes the basic parts of what Ubuntu uses for GUIs, including X and Wayland](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6322664398913536/)

And, of course, you can see [their full list of organizations](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/).